# How can I view how many downvotes I received on my questions across the SE network?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

I wonder how I can view how many downvotes I received on my questions across the SE network.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1368307/votes-on-your-posts-network-wide, try forking that query.  I'll get you an answer in a bit.

Comment: Also not sure how this needs more details or clarity, other than maybe "using SEDE", since, AFAIK, you can't any other way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want to do with that information. Personally, I'm more interested in how many people I helped, so I'd rather look at the number of upvotes and accept votes. Fortunately, SQL supports pivoting, so we can have a look at [everything at once](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1392280/votes-on-your-posts-network-wide?AccountId=169656). The number you're looking for is 2328 (well, it was last Sunday morning; the downvotes on this question (not mine) haven't been stored in SEDE yet).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, since total rep is given, that's pretty much equivalent.

Comment: Nice that dynamic pivot column handling.

Comment: Thanks @rene - I really think (T-)SQL should make this easier but as long as this works, I'm not complaining.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I now realize you asked for votes on *questions*, not all posts. If you're interested, you could fork the query and add `AND p.PostTypeId = 1` after `WHERE u.AccountId = ' + CAST(##AccountId:int## AS NVARCHAR) + '`.

Comment: @Glorfindel noted, thanks!

Comment: @Glorfindel well, FWIW, Microsoft Access does have a Transform statement: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/transform-statement-microsoft-access-sql that does allow **NOT** specifying the columns.